# Get name when user_type=1 and active=TRUE in DQL at Symfony2 Form

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I have a `n:m` relationship between two tables: `ServiceType` and `UserType` and this relies on a 3th table `ServiceUserType` as a n:m result. I'm trying from my form builder to get all the services where `user_type=1` and `active=TRUE` but this are columns from `ServiceUserType` table so I did this:

```
....
->add('servicio', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'CommonBundle:ServiceType',
    'property' => 'name',
    'mapped' => FALSE,
    'required' => FALSE,
    'label' => 'test',
    'expanded' => TRUE,
    'multiple' => TRUE,
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('ts')
                ->leftJoin('ts.service', 'su')
                ->where('su.user_type = 1')
                ->andWhere('su.active = TRUE');
    }
))
....
```

But I'm getting this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 81 near 'su WHERE su.user_type': Error: Class CommonBundle\Entity\ServiceType has no association named service

And I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any help? This are the `ServiceType` entity:

```
    class ServiceType
    {

        protected $id;
        protected $name;
        protected $active = true;
        ...

    }
```

And this other is `ServiceUserType`:

```
class ServiceUserType
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\CommonBundle\Entity\ServiceType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $service;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\CommonBundle\Entity\UserType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user_type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $active = true;
    ...
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class of servicio form field is ServiceType and when you query it will select the ServiceType entity as root. The ServiceType has no field named service, ServiceUserTypes has. What you can do is add the property bellow to your ServiceType entity:

```
/**
 *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\CommonBundle\Entity\ServiceUserType", mappedBy="service")
*/
protected $serviceUserTypes;
```

Then change your query:

```
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('ts')
                ->leftJoin('ts.serviceUserTypes', 'su')
                ->where('su.user_type = 1')
                ->andWhere('su.active = TRUE');
    }
```

Dont forget to add the inversedBy option on property service at ServiceUserType Class and set the property $serviceUserTypes equal to a new ArrayCollection on your constructor at Service Type class.